# Cannot access myself with global ip, others can

Tags: ip, port, forwarding

I don't really know how to phrase this better, so I'll just point out what works and what doesnt:

a) I can access my service through 127.0.0.1:port

b) My friend can access my service through x.x.x.x:port where x.x.x.x is my IP (ports forwarded)

c) I, in turn, cannot access my service through x.x.x.x:port

Does anyone know what this may be caused by and how can one fix this?

Comment: What are you talking about? What service? What OS? What network-setup?

Comment: What kind of router are you using? I know of a number that will not allow someone inside the network to access their own public IP in this manner. ( BT Homehub's here in the UK have this issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in your router settings for a feature called **[hairpin NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)** or **NAT loopback**.

In most routers, port forwardings only work from the outside by default, since the actual address translation (NAT) is also done only when packets exit or enter your LAN, not inside the LAN. Enabling NAT loopback should make the forwardings work from the inside too.

Comment: On that note, many consumer routers lack that feature. So the only way is to use the internal address.