# Can't connect to a game server from within my local network BUT others from outside the network can connect

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router

I have a game server hosted on a certain port in Ubuntu, which is port forwarded. Users from other places can successfully connect to that server. However, I can't connect to it from another computer within the same network. both computers are connected to the same network Router (F660 ZTE). I'm trying to connect from a Windows 10 PC. I've modified all the relevant firewall rules to no avail. It seems like a complete inability to connect, not just the client being denied access, as there are no indications of getting blocked out in the logs.

When I ping the server, there is just a total lack of communication, no connection until the pings timeout. This happens the other way arround as well.

For a while I managed to fix it by connecting using the local ip, but the problem suddenly came back again. Now I can't reach it in any way, be it the external or the internal IP.

Client OS: Windows 10

Server OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Game: Minecraft

Router: F660

Edit:: More research suggests this has something to do with "Hairpin NAT" or similar, but I don't know what to do afterwards

Exit 2: This isn't a duplicate, my problem wasn't fixed by that other question. I now added to my client's hosts file a rule so "yeet.com" is taken as the internal ip of my server, but the problem wasn't fixed.

Edit 3: No, those answers don't work. Uisng the internal ip is NOT a workaround in my case, but it seems to be a workaround in their case. Even connecting through internal ip is impossible

Comment: have you tried disabling your firewall temporarily?

Comment: Yes, doesn't do anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access outside service from inside LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/135366/unable-to-access-outside-service-from-inside-lan)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access myself with global ip, others can](https://superuser.com/questions/609928/cannot-access-myself-with-global-ip-others-can)

Comment: I can't connect even with my local ip, it doesn't seem to just be a  NAT hairpin issue

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your question to say, "I have two computers on the same network.   At one point, I was able to connect from one to another (on the local network, using the local IP address), but that stopped working.   P.S. I have port forwarding enabled on my router, and users can still access my server *from **outside** the local network.*"